# Testing to verify that a button is clicked first before another is clicked "Webfomrs"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, webforms

I used an if statement saying that if lblTotalAmount is populated then you can be able to click the second button. Because if lbltotalamount is populated then the first button was clicked to populate it. However, with my code below it works by showing the error message if you try to click the second button before the first button but then if i do it in the correct order it will not redirect me to the page i stated below. How can i correctly state this so that it will work?

protected void btnSubmitOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (lblTotalAmount == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please click the Calculate Order Total button first";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is this even necessary at all?  If the server has the logic to calculate the total amount, then why not calculate it?  Why force the user to make *two* requests and click *two* buttons when all of the calculations can be done in one?

Comment: `lblTotalAmount` is a label? However, `lblTotalAmount` is never null because it exists. I assume that it is a label, so you need to check if `lblTotalAmount.Text` is null or white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be trying to validate on the Text property of the lablel instead

```
protected void btnSubmitOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblTotalAmount.Text))
     {
           Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
     }
     else
     {
           lblMessage.Text = "Please click the Calculate Order Total button first";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Worked! Also with that had to switch the response in the else and message under the if. Thanks a bunch!